# Meaning of "! -S" in shell script

Tags: shell

I am new to shell scripting, and I have encountered a script I didn't understand:

```
DOWN=true
while $DOWN; do
    sleep 0.1
    DOWN=false
    for i in {1..7}
    do
    if [ ! -S "qdata/c$i/tm.ipc" ]; then
            DOWN=true
    fi
    done
done
```

Specifically, what does this command mean:

```
! -S "qdata/c$i/tm.ipc"
```

Comment: There is no such command.  There is an invocation of the `[` command with arguments `! -S "qdata/c$i/tmp.ipc" ]`

Comment: It is simply checking if the given path exists and is a socket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you are looking at is actually this:

```
[ ! -S "qdata/c$i/tm.ipc" ]
```

Although it looks like punctuation, `[` is actually the name of a command, also called `test`; so the command can also be written like this:

```
test ! -S "qdata/c$i/tm.ipc"
```

Which in context would look like this:

```
if test ! -S "qdata/c$i/tm.ipc"; then
        DOWN=true
fi
```

As the name suggests, its job is to *test* some attribute of a string, number, or file, and return `0` (which represents true in shell scripts) if the test passes, and `1` (which represents false) if it doesn't.

Armed with this knowledge, you can run `man test`, and find the following explanations of the `!` and `-S` arguments:

> ```
>    ! EXPRESSION
>          EXPRESSION is false
> ```

and

> ```
>    -S FILE
>          FILE exists and is a socket
> ```

So `test ! -S filename` or `[ ! -S filename ]` can be read as "not is-socket filename".

So the command is checking whether a "socket" (a special kind of file) exists with each name in the loop. The script uses this command as the argument to an `if` statement (which can take any command, not just `[`) and sets `DOWN` to `true` if any of them does *not* exist.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really specify which shell you're talking about since they can vary a lot.

To answer you question, the context is a common construct

```
if [ <some test> ]
then
<commands>
fi
```

Where the `[ <some test>]` is a call to [the command test](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/testh.html)

If you look at the documentation of that command you can see that `!` negates the result and `-S` checks for `True if file is a socket.`.

So you can read it as `if "qdata/c$i/tm.ipc" is not a socket`